# This is regarding vector space in linear algebra...

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the set of all positive real numbers.On $V$ define the addition and the scalar multiplication in the following manner.

addition:  $x+y = xy$

scalar multiplication : $rx= x^r$

Prove or disprove whether $V$ is a vector space.

***my answer***

chose $1,2$ belongs to $V$

$1+2=3$ not equal to $1\cdot2= 2$

hence $V$ is not closed under addition ,hence $V$ is not a vector space... is the answer simple as that??? please help me friends...it will be very useful for my  Linear Algebra exam...

Comment: You need to use a **different** symbol for the *new* addition operation so you don't *confuse* it with the *usual* addition operation. Say, use $\oplus$ for the new addition operation. Then $1\oplus 2:=1\times 2=2$, and there is nothing to say that $1+2$ equals $1\oplus 2$. No contradiction arises. In fact, $(0,\infty)$ *is* a real vector space under number multiplication as vector addition and number exponentiation as vector space scalar multiplication.

Comment: Hint: Take logarithms and observe $\ln(x\oplus y)=\ln x+\ln y$ and $\ln(r\odot x)=r\cdot\ln x$

Comment: @anon : sir i have another problem.if you can give me a help it is highly appreciated..

 let V be a vector space and let {u1,u2,...un} be a basis for V.

suppose 


v1=U1 , v2=u1+u2  , v3=u1+u2+u3, ......vn=u1+u2+....un

prove or disprove whether {v1,v2,...,vn} is a basis for V

please help me friends...

Comment: @ChampR If you have a different question, post it as such and don't use the comments for doing so.

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer : the problem is mister I can't post this as another question because the site says after I post the question "This post does not meet our quality standards." :-( and dont publish the question...

Comment: @ChampR This is an automatic message that sometimes happens. To prevent this you just have to rewrite the question slightly. E.g. (which is also helpful for you and the potential answerers) include some definitions or theorems you think might be relevant. Or sketch what you have tried, e.g. calculating an example.

Answer (score 1):

Every field is a vector space (of dimension 1) over itself, whith addition given by the additive structure of the field, and scalar multiplication given by the multiplicative structure. In your case, there is simply a change of notation: the sum is denoted as a product, and consistently the product $rx$ becomes a power $x^r$.

For the other question you raised in the comments, consider that the matrix associated to the map sending $u_i$'s to $v_i$'s is of the form (e.g. take $n=3$)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1&0&0\\
1&1&0\\
1&1&1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
u_1\\
u_2\\
u_3
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
u_1\\
u_1+u_2\\
u_1+u_2+u_3
\end{array}
\right)$$

The matrix is invertible ( $\det=1$), hence the map also is, so it is a linear bijective map, and you should know that such a map sends a basis in a basis